# Cannot use decorators in Node/BabelJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have a Node application, which specifies babel with transform options and register in a main file, like so:

```
require('babel').transform('code', { stage: 1 });
require('babel/register')({ ignore: false });
require('../src/index');
```

Which does an excellent job of allowing me to use ES6 in `../src/index`, and all subsequent files, but does not seem to allow me to use Decorators, as it should by declaring level 1 transform. I get instead a syntax error. Why is this not enabling decorator support? The actual decorator I'm trying to use is:

```
@test1
test Class() {
    constructor() {
        this.test = 'test';
    }
}

function test1(obj) {
    obj.test1 = 'test1';
}
```

Comment: Also, what is `test Class`? That's not valid class syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you specify options, that first like does nothing. It compiles the JavaScript code `code` and does nothing with the result of the compilation.

```
require('babel/register')({
    ignore: false,
    stage: 1
});
require('../src/index');
```

Also generally `ignore: false` is a bad idea because some files should ignored.

#### Update

If you are using Babel 6, you'll want to download `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` rather than enabling `stage: 1`.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I've noticed as I add more to my project, just setting ignore to false is significantly slowing down my package. I'll have to be more selective of what I load.

Comment: Yup!, I just copied it because you had it in your original question, it's definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the newest version of babel (v6) (over 1 month old) does not support decorators and the babeljs team has identified that they do not consider decorators to be a priority to fix -

https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/661501967412301824

As @jdanyow has mentioned in other answers you can track the issue [here](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645) but beware if you choose to use Babeljs v6 that there is functionality from the previous release which is broken in the released v6 at the moment.

As @loganfsmyth points out in comments there is a plugin available [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) although it does mention that there are differences in the implementation, however I am not aware of them.

Comment: That tweet is a month and a half old. As posted in the issue you linked to, [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) is available and works very well.

Comment: Works very well - Info from that link - Beware, this plugin is a best effort to maintain feature parity with Babel 5, but there are slight differences if you were relied on side-effects between decorators in some cases.  Doesn't sound very reliable definitely a rock and a hard place situation.  @loganfsmyth I did update the answer with your information though

Comment: I can update that text (I wrote it) :P The main noticable differences should be very minimal if any.